# How to make a family tree app using React Native?

Tags: react-native

For school, I have to make my first app with React Native. It's a family tree app; my teacher said it's the best choice to make that with all `View`-elements, even the lines between family members. But I think that won't ever be possible to calculate all distances perfectly.
Isn't there any other way to make this kind of app?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right and you need to take something like https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg

With SVG you can draw shapes and arrows to connect your tree items.
For React exists a beautiful library called https://reactflow.dev. Unfortunately, it is a Web-only solution, but you can check how they render trees and repeat it in RN.

Also, read this article about storing tree data in JS https://medium.com/@iampika/javascript-trees-b8f3b4261c3a it should be helpful.

Comment: All right, thank you. Using the svg's that's way more easy. Now I just have to find out what's the best way to position everything at the correct place, because the amount of family members is different for every family.